# Hilbert series for symmetric polynomial ring

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials

Consider $\mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]^{S_n}$. I want to calculate the Hilbert series for this. To do this, I'm trying to find out the dimension of the space of homogeneous symmetric polynomials of degree $d$. I'm stuck on this part - I'm not sure how to go about this combinatorially. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: It is the number of non-negative tulles, $(i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n)$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^n ki_k=d.$ This is the number of partitions of $d$ into numbers $\leq n.$ The topic of counting such things is extensive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Right now this is a little low on context - what do you know about symmetric polynomials? (For instance, do you know the fundamental theorem?) Have you made any attempts of your own, possibly with small values of $n$ and $d$?

Comment: In the notation from Wikipedia, the value is $p_1(d)+p_2(d)+\cdots +p_n(d).$

Comment: It is also the coefficient of $x^d$ in $$\prod_{i=1}^n\frac1{1-x^k}$$ oh, I forgot this is the defintion of the Hilbert series.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thank you! That's helpful.